# Why I can not call Implementation method from library class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-components, laravel-service-container

In laravel 9 app I created class  app/Implementations/LocalStorageUploadedFileManagement.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Implementations;

use App\Interfaces\UploadedFileManagement;
...
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image as Image;

class LocalStorageUploadedFileManagement implements UploadedFileManagement
{
    ...
    public function getImageFileDetails(string $itemId, string $image = null, string $itemUploadsDirectory = '',
        bool $skipNonExistingFile = false): array {
        \Log::info('++ getImageFileDetails$image ::');
        \Log::info( $image );

    }
    ...
```

and Interface class in app/Interfaces/UploadedFileManagement.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Interfaces;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

interface UploadedFileManagement
{
    ...
    public function getImageFileDetails(string $itemId, string $image = null, string $itemUploadsDirectory = '',
        bool $skipNonExistingFile = false): array;

}
```

In app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php I have:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Interfaces\UploadedFileManagement', 'App\Implementations\LocalStorageUploadedFileManagement');
        
    }
```

so I can use it in my controller app/Http/Controllers/Admin/ProductController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
...
use App\Interfaces\UploadedFileManagement;

class ProductController extends Controller  // http://local-mng-products.com/admin/products
{

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function edit(string $productId, UploadedFileManagement $uploadedFileManagement)
    {
        ...
        $productImgProps = $uploadedFileManagement->getImageFileDetails(
            itemId : $product->_id,
            itemUploadsDirectory : Product::getUploadsProductDir(),
            image : $product->image,
            skipNonExistingFile : true);
        
        ...
```

abd it works ok

But I got error :

```
Cannot instantiate interface App\Interfaces\UploadedFileManagement
```

when I try to use UploadedFileManagement in library app/Library/ReportProduct.php class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Library;

use App\Interfaces\UploadedFileManagement;
...
class ReportProduct
{

    public function getImageProps()
    {
        $uploadedFileManagement= new UploadedFileManagement();  // This line raised the error
        $imgProps = $uploadedFileManagement->getImageFileDetails($this->product->_id, $this->product->image, Product::getUploadsProductDir(),true);
        return $imgProps;
    }
```

getImageProps method is called from ProductCardReport component, which I created with command :

```
php artisan make:component  ProductCardReport
```

and it has in file app/View/Components/ProductCardReport.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use App\Library\ReportProduct;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class ProductCardReport extends Component
{
    public string $productId;

    public function __construct(string $productId)
    {
        $this->productId = $productId;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $reportProduct = new ReportProduct($this->productId);
        $reportProduct->loadProduct();
        $productData = $reportProduct->getProductData(true);

        $productImgProps = $reportProduct->getImageProps();
        ...
```

Why I got error in ReportProduct.php class on using of UploadedFileManagement service?

How that can be done ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
I tried  to inject it in the same way I did in ProductController edit function.
But I failed as If I try to edit app/Library/ReportProduct.php with similar injection :

```
<?php

namespace App\Library;

use App\Interfaces\UploadedFileManagement;
...

class ReportProduct
{
    public function __construct(Product | string $product, UploadedFileManagement $uploadedFileManagement = null)
    {
        $this->uploadedFileManagement = $uploadedFileManagement;
        ...
```

But as I create ReportProduct and call getImageProps from app/View/Components/ProductCardReport.php component
I need to UploadedFileManagement class from somewhere for the 1st time . I can not inject
UploadedFileManagement in app/View/Components/ProductCardReport.php.
Not shure how injection works here and how can I use it in chain  Component->customClass?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valid decision is :

```
$uploadedFileManagement= app(UploadedFileManagement::class);
$productImgProps = $uploadedFileManagement->getImageFileDetails(
    itemId : $product->_id,
    itemUploadsDirectory : Product::getUploadsProductDir(),
    image : $product->image,
    skipNonExistingFile : true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `UploadedFileManagement` is an object [`interface`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) and interfaces are not instantiable (a fancy way of saying you can't create an instance of an interface - i.e. `new UploadedFileManagement()`).

Binding an `interface` and an `implementation` in the Laravel service container doesn't magically transform your code to use the `implementation` wherever you have made use of the `interface`. All it does is tell Laravel how to resolve a dependency when it encounters one.

To clarify this when you run your application

```
$service = new UploadedFileManagement();
```

Doesn't get converted to

```
$service = new LocalStorageUploadedFileManagement();
```

That is not how dependency injection or the service container work.

If you want to make use of your `LocalStorageUploadedFileManagement()` class in the `ReportProduct` class, you will need to inject it in the same way you have done with your `ProductController` `edit` function.

Comment: Please look MODIFIED BLOCK